# warning: (Internal error: pc 0x804a6b0 in read in psymtab, but not in symtab.) g++

Tags: gdb, g++, ddd-debugger

I am trying to debug a program using ddd. When I try to enter any function, or within `main()` itself, I get the following warning:

> warning: (Internal error: pc 0x804a6b0 in read in psymtab, but not in symtab.)

This warning flashes whenever I try to move to another instruction using `n` or enter or leave a function. I have tried to look this up in other forums, but with no conclusive answer. The code I am trying to debug runs into several files and I am not sure if I can post the entire code here.

I am using g++ version:
g++ (GCC) 4.4.1 20090725 (Red Hat 4.4.1-2)

Any help on this is most welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ks1322 is correct to suggest that the problem is likely to be due to a bug in gdb which has been corrected.   I think the relevant description and patch are described in the following link.

http://sourceware.org/ml/gdb-patches/2003-01/msg00074.html

I can confirm that when I also encountered this problem in a C++ application under gdb 6.8, updating to gdb 7.2 resolved it.

Comment: Il update gdb to the relevant version and try this out. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Unfortunately, GDB 7.2 still demonstrates the same behavior — whether due to the same bug or another.

Comment: Same as Anton. I had this message with GDB 7.2 but it did not happen with 7.6 though.

Comment: Just as a note I've just encountered the same error with GDB 7.0 on CentOS (7.0.1-45.el5.centos) so this issue is not fixed in that version.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use more recent version of gdb (7.0 or 7.1)